# ASP.NET MVC: for Url.Action generate default route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Is there a way to force the generation of the default action when using Url.Action?

For instance, if I do this:

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Something")
```

It won't generate the Index portion in the URL, so I'll end up with /..../Something. I'd like to get the Index part in the URL because I'm injecting it in the page so that I can get the correct URL for navigation (which looks like /.../Something/Index/1).

Thanks

Luis

Comment: please provide me your complete example where you want to use action??

Comment: I need to build and URL, but the ID will only be dynamically set in javascript.  I'm using the routes generated by default

Comment: `/..../Something` *is* the correct URL for navigation. Routing will always build the shortest URL possible, ignoring all of the optional segments on the right-hand side (otherwise your home page would be at `/Home/Index` instead of `/`).

Comment: Hello. Yes, I understand that what I'm seeing is the expected behavior...was just wondering if there was any option of changing it...it seems like there isn't...